# Approach for creating RestFul web services in Spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, jersey, restful-architecture

I want to develop RestFul web service using Spring. When I googled, I found that it can be done in two ways. One way is to use Spring's own Spring MVC and the other way is to use Jersey (or any other JAX-RS implementation) that provides support for Spring. I would like to know which approach would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s something to be said for the cleanliness that is inherent to the JAX-RS spec. Whereas the Spring MVC approach is sufficient, JAX-RS is targeted solely to implementing REST APIs. Spring MVC isn’t built for that purpose alone and personally, I think it shows. Sometimes it can be a bit verbose or confusing.

For example, if you omit a method on a Spring MVC REST controller, Spring MVC happily assumes you want to have this endpoint available for all HTTP methods. For MVC purposes, this might be okay, for REST, this is not. And if you add the method to the @RequestMapping, you suddenly can’t use the terse notation and need to explicitly declare the value parameter on the notation. Same thing with setting explicit MIME types for an endpoint.

At the moment, I haven’t found anything that Spring MVC can do for REST which JAX-RS couldn’t.

P.S. It's the developer's choice. Technically one can build the same web service with both.